# How to compile the Oracle Instant Client Libraries for PHP PDO - Linux x86_64?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I'm currently trying to compile the Oracle Instant Client Libraries for PHP PDO (Linux x86_64) and it's failing on the make step. Note: this is an old experimental plugin.

I've followed the steps highlighted on this page: http://lacot.org/blog/2009/11/03/ubuntu-php5-oci8-and-pdo_oci-the-perfect-install.html and it fails on `make`.

Do you have any idea what this error means? or how i can correct it?
I think i means that the `zend_fcall_info` type is not being recognised but as far as i can see the zend.h file is being included ok since i've copied all of the Zend includes into /usr/local/include/php/ext/pdo/ to try and resolve this error.

```
gary@gary-desktop:/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0$ make /bin/bash
/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/libtool --mode=compile gcc
-I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I. -I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC
-I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/include -I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/main -I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0
-I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main
-I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend 
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c -o pdo_oci.lo 
gcc -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I. -I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC
-I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/include -I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/main -I/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0
-I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main
-I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend
-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o
pdo_oci.lo In file included from /tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0/pdo_oci.c:29:
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h:617: error: expected
specifier-qualifier-list before 'zend_fcall_info'
/usr/local/include/php/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h:624: error: expected
specifier-qualifier-list before 'zend_fcall_info' make: ***
[pdo_oci.lo] Error 1 gary@gary-desktop:/tmp/PDO_OCI-1.0$
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another machine and all worked fine. It was probably a configuration issue.